# Data set recognizes 12:00AM as 00:00AM

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am receiving the following error from Python:

```
ValueError: time data '05/10/2015 00:19:49 AM' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'
```

I believe that the reason for this is that the data set is slightly inconsistent with the way the `datetime` library recognizes the 12 midnight time. I think it probably needs to be rectified by changing the `00` to `12` instead.

For example, the following data is displayed as follows:

```
05/10/2015 12:59:12 PM
```

The data is not using a 24 hour clock. Does anyone have a way of resolving this?

Comment: What do other dates look like? Are the times in 24 hour format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a simple `try`- `except`, trying `%I` first and using `%H` if you get a `ValueError`:

```
date_string = '05/10/2015 00:19:49 AM'
try:
    date = time.strptime(date_string, '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
except ValueError:
    date = time.strptime(date_string, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')

print(time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p', date))
```

Output:

```
05/10/2015 00:19:49 AM
```

The `%I` should work for all dates in 12-hour format except those with `00` for the hour. For these cases the 24-hour format using `%H` should work fine.

Works the same with `datetime`:

```
import datetime

date_string = '05/10/2015 00:19:49 AM'
try:
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
except ValueError:
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')

print(date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p'))
```

Output:

```
05/10/2015 00:19:49 AM
```